# JLabel Not Showing Up Besides My JText

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

I am not able to get how to put up a text besides my button or text fields, when I made a separate code for just the label and a text field(copied as it from the internet) it is working, but it isn't in this case, please tell me how do I make it work? I got an idea like I might have to use some frame or some layout, but is it necessary? Just the basics please. Thanks. :

```
public class UIClass extends JFrame {

public UIClass()
{   super("GUIPart1");
    super.setBounds(50,50,1000,700);
    super.setResizable(true);
    super.setVisible(true);
    super.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    // Button
    JButton btn1=new JButton();
    btn1.setBounds(50,50, 100, 50);
    super.add(btn1);
    super.setLayout(null);
    btn1.setText("Test"); 

    //TextField
    JTextField tf1=new JTextField(15);
    super.add(new JLabel("Label :"));
    super.add(tf1);
    tf1.setBounds(100,100,200,200);


    //OptionPane
    JOptionPane text=new JOptionPane();
    String Message=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("My Message");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you");


}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    UIClass u=new UIClass();

}
}
```

Comment: FlowLayout is default LayoutManager, use something that fits better your needs - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html Calling `super` is a bit strange, you can replace it with this, which makes more sense or skip it at all...

Comment: `BorderLayout` is very easy to start with

Comment: I want to know why the label isnt showing up in this code while it is in this one :
public class Test extends JFrame{
 private Test()
 {  JTextField numberField = new JTextField(15);
   

  add(new JLabel("Number to double (n):"), BorderLayout.WEST);
     add(numberField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    
 }

Comment: For your `TextField` you provide the coordinates - for your `Label` you do not.

Comment: I tried doing that too, but even that didn't work 
   'JLabel jl=new JLabel("Label : ");
  jl.setBounds(300,300,400,400);
  super.add(jl);'

Comment: *"I might have to use some frame or some layout, but is it necessary?"* Yes. Note that both current answers give generally poor advice. Hacks to cover up the deficiencies in this approach. Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call

```
this.repaint();
```

at the end. I wouldn't recommend using `setBounds` in JavaDoc it reads:

> This method changes layout-related information, and therefore, invalidates the component hierarchy.

It was shown, when you resize window. This is valid for code with

```
JLabel jl=new JLabel("Label : "); jl.setBounds(300,300,400,400); super.add(jl);
```

as you mentioned in comment...

Comment: This worked, it also worked when I changed the declaration to : `JLabel jl=new JLabel("Label : ",JLabel.CENTER);`

Also can you tell me what's the suggested way to add a label to a textfield/button at the basic level, so that it automatically positions before the textfield.

Answer (score 0):

In your original code you explicitly set container layout to null.
In this case you must specify the position and the size of every other component you add and you did it for the button and textfield components only.

The code you posted in your comment you use BorderLayout as LayoutManager which automatically resizes and positions every component according to his strategy.

I strongly reccomend you to learn how to use LayoutManagers, because they are such a critical component in the Java UI environment, at least BorderLayout and GridLayout, because if your application is not too complex they should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks , I got the concept,will learn about it too, I am totally new to this and still learning.  So can you also tell me what's the suggested way to add a label to a textfield/button at the basic level, so that it automatically positions before the textfield?

Comment: JPanel jp = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); JLabel jl = new JLabel("label");JTextField jt = new JTextField();jp.add(jl, BorderLayout.WEST);jp.add(jt, BorderLayout.CENTER);